# get all domain names on network

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, dns

i need to get the list of domain names on my network...

but i am only getting the domain name with which i log into...
so for example there are 2 domains "xyz" and "xyz2" 
but i get only the domain with which i log into....

here is my code:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            StringCollection adDomains = this.GetDomainList();

                foreach (string strDomain in adDomains)
                {
                    DropDownList1.Items.Add(strDomain);

                }
            }
        }

    private StringCollection GetDomainList()
    {
        StringCollection domainList = new StringCollection();
        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry en = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://");
            // Search for objectCategory type "Domain"
            DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher("objectCategory=Domain");
            SearchResultCollection coll = srch.FindAll();
            // Enumerate over each returned domain.
            foreach (SearchResult rs in coll)
            {
                ResultPropertyCollection resultPropColl = rs.Properties;
                foreach (object domainName in resultPropColl["name"])
                {
                    domainList.Add(domainName.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        return domainList;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;
```

....

```
Forest currentForest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();  
DomainCollection domains = currentForest.Domains;  
foreach(Domain objDomain in domains)  
{  
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(objDomain.Name);  
}
```

Comment: BEWARE: This will not work when the app is ran as a local user.