# How to find out that my Windows user is a domain user?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I need find out that  my windows currentuser is domain user or local user?
I get My CurrentPrincipal with this:

```
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally the windows NON domain user doesn't have a UPN name. Like below If I fire WHOAMI with /upn:

```
C:\>WHOAMI /UPN
ERROR: Unable to get User Principal Name (UPN) as the current logged-on user
       is not a domain user.
```

Based on this using below code we can find whether the user is domain user or not.

```
 var upnName = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.UserPrincipalName;
    if (upnName == null)
    {
        //not a domain user
    }
```

The other lengthy way would be to get the user name in SAM format. Then using DirectoryEntry, DirectorySearcher and other AD API's iterate through all the joined domain of the machine and find if the user is in any of the domain we iterate.

Find all domains of the machine [ex1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697002/finding-all-domains-for-a-machine-in-c-sharp) and [ex2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633751/get-all-domain-names-on-network)

[Here is How to get domain user information from Active Directory in C#](http://weblogs.asp.net/jpinquie/archive/2008/02/06/how-to-get-domain-user-information-from-active-directory-in-c.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have no AD at my disposal but I would expect that this might work:

```
public bool IsDomainUser()
{
  bool isDomain = false; 
  foreach (var grp in WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups)
  {
      if (grp.IsValidTargetType(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)))
      {
        SecurityIdentifier si = 
                (SecurityIdentifier)grp.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
        // not sure if this is right, but I'm not in a domain and don't have this SID
        // I do have LocalSID however, so you might need to turn it around,
        // if you have LocalSid you are not using a domain acount
        if (si.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinDomainSid))
        {
            isDomain = true;
        }
      }
   }
   return isDomain;
 }



   // for debugging list SIDS for current user and its groups
   foreach (var obj in Enum.GetValues(typeof(WellKnownSidType)))
   {

    if (WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.IsWellKnown((WellKnownSidType)obj))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("User:" + obj.ToString());

    }

    foreach (var grp in WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups)
    {
        if (grp.IsValidTargetType(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)))
        {
            SecurityIdentifier si = 
                 (SecurityIdentifier) grp.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
            if (si.IsWellKnown((WellKnownSidType)obj))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Grp: " + grp.ToString() + " : " + obj.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Looks interesting, a new way. Curious about few things. Above, the SID's of the current user's member groups are checked for domain SID. Right? It means the domain user always has some group membership? Also the `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Group`, can it fetch group membership from domain?

Comment: If I look at the SIDs for my local account I get quite a few and I'm not a member of that many groups. I suppose you can only tell if you are dealing with a domain or local account and that is it. If you need assigned groupmembership you need to query the domain controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

bool IsDomainUser()
{
    return UserPrincipal.Current.ContextType == ContextType.Domain;
}
```